# How can i make this command to be used once in 3 days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im making a command that sends an api key for my website but i don't want it to get abused so i need the command to be used once in 3 days (72 hours) Or once in 2 days or even 1 day i just don't want it to get regenerated every second

This is my code atm

```
@bot.command()
async def key(ctx):
  await ctx.send(next(keys))
```

By the way if you're curious the api keys are in a txt file.

Comment: You should look there : https://ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the last access timestamp to a file and check if the cooldown time has already passed with [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-timedelta)
You could do it like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


@bot.command()
async def key(ctx):
    def save_timestamp(timestamp):  # Function to save the timestamp to file
        timestamp = int(timestamp)
        with open("last_credentials.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(timestamp))

    try:  # Try reading last credentials usage from file 'last_credentials.txt'
        with open("last_credentials.txt", 'r') as f:
            timestamp = int(f.read())

    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Create new timestamp if the file does not exist
        timestamp = datetime(year=1970, day=1, month=1).timestamp()

    creds_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

    if datetime.now() - creds_datetime > timedelta(hours=72):  # check if 3 days have passed from last usage. You could also use days=3 instead of hours=72
        save_timestamp(datetime.now().timestamp())
        await ctx.send(next(keys))
```

You could also store this timestamp in memory, but that would not keep last timestamp in case you would restart your program

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this repo: https://github.com/gawel/aiocron

This allows you to run crontab jobs with discord bot and if you want to run it every three day you will just use this :

```
0 12 */3 * *
```

Which will be running at 12:00 every 3 days (you can change the time)